# Find time complexity of nested loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity of the following piece of code

```cpp
for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=i; j < i*i; j++)
    {
        for(k=0; k<j; k++)
            count++;
    }
}
```

I am thinking it is O(n^4) but I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: The complexity of this loop would be `O ( N * K * J ) ` where `K=i^2`. Usually when considering optimizations to be done , you take all the dimensions as being equal so in your case you could say : `O(n^3)` since you run 3 loops.

Answer (score 0):

As written it doesn't terminate (for `n`>0), since `k` is never updated. Assuming a typo, and replacing the final `j++` with `k++`, then `count` eventually becomes sum_(i=0)^(n - 1)( sum_(j=i)^(i^2 - 1) j) = 1/60 (n - 2) (n - 1) n (6 n^2 + 3 n - 13) which is O(n^5).

The formula as an image:

[image: sum_(i=0)^(n - 1)( sum_(j=i)^(i^2 - 1) j) = 1/60 (n - 2) (n - 1) n (6 n^2 + 3 n - 13)]

I used wolfram alpha to compute the sums:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum%28j%2C+j+%3D+i...i%5E2-1%29%2C+i%3D0...n-1%29

Comment: Yes that was a typo, Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

To get the complexity, you must think top down :

1. Your superior loop implies a complexity superior to O(n)
2. Your second loop is more tricky. It goes from a number i to its square, making i^2-i steps which is O(i^2).
3. Your third loop does j steps.

Now we have all of your complexities, we can aggregate them :

1. n is O(n), obviously
2. j is 0(n^2)
3. k is O(j) = O(n^2)

All you have to do in the end is to multiply them and we get O(n^5)

Comment: This method (finding an upper bound for each loop and then multiplying them) is commonly used and produces a valid upper bound, but only produces a tight bound in some cases. This question happens to be such a case, but for example `for(i=1; i < n; i *= 2) for (j=0; j<i; j++) count++` it gives O(n log n) rather than the more accurate O(n).

Comment: @PaulHankin your example is interesting, how do you get O(n) complexity?

Comment: The result is the sum of all powers of 2 less than n, which is always less than 2n.